# Graph API feed does not return all posts

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

The request for this user's feed:
https://graph.facebook.com/100001402521962/feed?access_token=token

Does not contain the post:
https://graph.facebook.com/229728763750539?access_token=token

Yet it returns this post (also by the owner):
https://graph.facebook.com/229728763750539?access_token=token

Is there some reason that post 229728763750539 is not available in the feed?

Comment: Is this the same problem as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894473/facebook-graph-api-news-feed-does-not-return-the-right-data

Comment: I have the same problem. I have [report the bug to Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/180536925362509) and waiting.