# Facebook Graph API News Feed does not return the right data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to show a very simple version of the Facebook wall on my site (http://simplewall.net) but I can't get the whole user's wall.

The Facebook Graph API does not send the same thing to my app that it show me in it's graph API documentation.

I've tried this :

In my browser open : https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

then

On the Facebook Graph API Doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
and click the News feed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=... link.

The restults are not the same!

My app request for the following permissions : read_stream, user_status, friends_status

Comment: This may be a Facebook bug. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/180536925362509?browse=search_4ece6db8a55468a76168160